# Confusion over O(M+N) being more correct than O(2N) for multiple parameters in code

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I have heard how the correct or tightest upper bound in this code would be O(N+M). My question is why would saying O(N+N) be wrong. I have heard how this would be a loose or false upper bound. If that is the case, how do we know if O(n) is < O(m), or how do we know if O(n) > O(m)? The main reason I keep seeing is that we use O(N + M) over O(2N) is because there is no guarantee if O(N) = O(M). My confusion is how can we not tell that O(N) = O(M) is true? Clearly we have two simple for loop that run linearly, which will allow us to add them in my head and make it O(N + N). Where am I going wrong? Is it because we do not know if the two linear growth rates have any relation? If that is the case in regular math we can add 2x with 3x and make it 2x+5x knowing that both linear growth rates are different.

```
public void ex(int n, int m)
{
int i - 0;
int j = 0; 
while(i < n)
{ 
    i++: 
}
while(j < m)
{
    j++; 
}
}
```

Comment: First of all `O(2N)` is actually just `O(N)` - we want just the variable part that changes the most in the big-O notation. Second, `O(N+M)` is more correct because the *only* time it equals `O(2N)` is if `N = M`. Every other time, and there is infinitely many of them (OK, bound by the size of `int` but still), it's different. Still, in "common parlance" we can say it's `O(N)` because sometimes we only really care that it's linear growth.

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't know if N will be equal to M & there are two loops, hence O(N+M).
We cannot say O(N+N) or O(M+M) because N and M may widely differ.

Lets say one iteration of while loop takes 1 second.
Consider N=5 & M=10000.

So, 5 second +10000 second = 10005 second.

Now if you would have considered O(N+N), then its just about 10 second.

If you would have considered O(M+M), then its about 20000 seconds.

Both of which differ greatly.

Hence O(N+M) is better and accurate.

Of course, if N is almost equal to M, then we can say O(N+N) which is again equivalent to O(N) because we drop the constants (2 in this case).

But, in any case, overall it has linear time complexity.

Comment: The thing is though how are we able to consider such precise seconds? In terms of code there is no way to tell that tell for how long something will take seconds wise because that is very computer dependent. Whenever we use Big O to analyze code we just do a high level overview, I thought we did not have to worry about such precise measurements.

Comment: Of course, the code is computer dependent. I just used seconds for explanation and try to show the difference between O(N+M) , O(N+N) and O(M+M). We do high level overview to eliminate the programming language dependency, computer dependency or any thing else the run time of code might depend on.